PCB layout guidelines Magnetic Sensor
I am using this IC from TI in my design.
The layout design guidelines and typical layout is given below.

I have some questions regarding the layout guidelines.
It says that
"Common passive components and some PCB plating materials contain ferromagnetic materials that are magnetizable & Use nonmagnetic passive components (for example, decoupling capacitors and the shunt resistor) to prevent
magnetizing effects near the DRV425."
May I know can I use ceramic capacitors,Chip Resistors and FR4 pcb material?.
"Do not use PCB trace finishes with nickel-gold plating because of the potential for magnetization."
Then which plating I need to use?
Layout

You can see vias placed in the thermal pad(black in color)
As per my knowledge I should place soldermask on these vias.Please correct me if I am wrong.

That whole bottom square pad should be solderable.  Not just the vias.

Yes,my question is about via solder mask.

Regarding the PCB finish, you can use HASL (lead-free or not) or OPC, but not ENIG.
ENIG (Electroless Nickel Immersion Gold) sometimes just called "gold flash" has a nickel barrier layer, and nickel is ferromagnetic.

Some SMT resistors and ceramic capacitors are non-magnetic, and some are not. Many through-hole parts have plated steel leads. Parts sold specifically as non-magnetic may be hard to source and expensive, but they are available. Otherwise you can test with a magnet (and hope that the manufacturer doesn't make changes during your production run, confirmed by incoming inspection).
Here is the BOM of the evaluation module. The resistors and capacitors do not appear to be special non-magnetic types and I see no reference in the manual to that characteristic:


You should not put any solder mask on the component side of the pad. You can put solder mask on the bottom.
To confirm, look at the official TI DRV425EVM eval board:

(layout images below created from an Altium file retrieved from here):


TI's recommended footprint has a 0.203mm via hole diameter, so I don't think you need to worry about wicking or using expensive via plugging if you use their footprint, but the hole size is smaller than the default minimum via holes size of some of the lower end PCB services.


In this layout they did not kept solder mask is not kept in the bottom also.Please correct me if I am wrong.What about solder wicking if mask is not present in the component side

There's solder mask on the bottom, bottom image. No solder mask on the pads. If you mean they didn't tent the vias, that is true. I don't think wicking will be a problem since it's  huge area compared to 4 small via holes. They cut and pasted some stuff about thermal pads in the part datasheet but I don't think this part has much power dissipation so the thermal pad layout you have is excessive.

I find that almost all SMD ceramic and tantalum capacitors and and some SMD resistors are ferromagnetic, contrary to this answer. (I tried and the parts in my collection stick to a magnet.)

@jpa Interesting, I'll edit. Checking some parts I have around, some of the X7R and NP0 are magnetic, some are not and no resistors I checked were. Thanks.

Digikey, for example, has only a very limited  selection of non-magnetic SMT resistors and capacitors in stock. For example, these ones- which are maybe 100x more expensive than ordinary 100nF/16V parts. Maybe some of the parts can be placed further away from the sensitive area.

May I know the issue with ENIG finish

@Confused ENIG has "N" = Nickel as a barrier layer between the gold and the copper. Nickel is ferromagnetic. The nickel layer is directly in contact with the chip so it is going to have more effect than slightly magnetic parts further away. You can verify this with a strong magnet and an ENIG PCB, but the effect is quite small. I balanced an ENIG board on a precision rod and was able to get the board to see-saw with a magnet attracted to a TO252 pad.


May I know can I use ceramic capacitors,Chip Resistors and FR4 pcb material?.

I don't see an issue using ceramic capacitors. I would consider using NP0 or X7R capacitors since both or used for magnetic-sensitive designs.
Using thick or thin film chips for your resistors would a good choice since they are also used for magnetic-sensitive designs.
Since FR4 is a glass-reinforced epoxy laminate, it's non-magnetic so that would be fine. Truthfully, its probably one of the most ubiquitous choices for PCB fabrication.

Then which plating I need to use?

This is kind of a tricky question because there disadvantages for different types of materials but if your only concern is that you're looking for something that's not magnetic, I would probably use immersion tin if you're looking to keep cost down (or if cost is not a concern, then use immersion silver). I may also recommend OSP but you mentioned thermal concerns so that may not be the best solution.

As per my knowledge I should place soldermask on these vias. Please correct me if I am wrong.

That would be a good idea. It can prevent solder wicking, i.e. solder that can flow through a via onto the other side of the board during reflow. It's also a good practice for thermal dissipation.
Texas Instruments has a rather detailed document here that talks about this specific topic for their PowerPAD™ design.

To be precise, solder mask should not go between component and EPAD, but on the opposite side of the board. OP has specifically asked about soldermask on component side elsewhere in the comments.

@MrGerber The TI appnote tends to differ: "if the thermal vias are not plugged when the copper plating is performed, then a solder mask material should be used to cap the vias on the component side". I have also seen some sources suggest that capping with soldermask only on the opposite side can trap air and the expanding bubbles would cause issues while soldering.

In regards to the via question, what the layout is showing is called ``via in pad''. The PCB fabricator needs to do the following additional steps:

Drill the via hole through the copper pad.
Plate the inside of the hole with copper.
Fill the hole with epoxy.
Planarize the pad (flatten it) so that the via ``nail head'' doesn't stick up too high and interfere with soldering the component.
Plate the pad.

Additional fabrication steps usually result in additional charges.
On the side opposite of the component on the board, sometimes there is a hole in the solder mask that covers the via (the ``via tenting''). Filling the hole with epoxy in step #3 prevents solder paste from going down the drain when soldering.
When we make a PCB with via in pad we usually specify the following in the fabrication notes:

The last sentence is because some fabricators ask if filling all the vias, including the vias that are not via in pad, is acceptable. I assume it's easier for them to apply the process to all the vias, instead of some.
The fabricator will ask if you want electrically conductive epoxy or non-conductive epoxy. A fabricator once said that non-conductive epoxy is cheaper, but I don't know if this is universal.
